# python: using .iterrows() to create columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to use a loop function to create a matrix of whether a product was seen in a particular week.

Each row in the df (representing a product) has a close_date (the date the product closed) and a week_diff (the number of weeks the product was listed).

```
import pandas
mydata = [{'subid' : 'A', 'Close_date_wk': 25, 'week_diff':3},
          {'subid' : 'B', 'Close_date_wk': 26, 'week_diff':2},
          {'subid' : 'C', 'Close_date_wk': 27, 'week_diff':2},]
df = pandas.DataFrame(mydata)
```

My goal is to see how many alternative products were listed for each product in each date_range

I have set up the following loop:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    i = 0
    max_range = row['Close_date_wk']    
    min_range = int(row['Close_date_wk'] - row['week_diff'])
    for i in range(min_range,max_range):
        col_head = 'job_week_'  +  str(i)
        row[col_head] = 1
```

Can you please help explain why the "row[col_head] = 1" line is neither adding a column, nor adding a value to that column for that row.

For example, if:

```
row A has date range 1,2,3 
row B has date range 2,3  
row C has date range 3,4,5'
```

then ideally I would like to end up with

```
row A has 0 alternative products in week 1
          1 alternative products in week 2
          2 alternative products in week 3
row B has 1 alternative products in week 2
          2 alternative products in week 3
&c..
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can't mutate the df using `row` here to add a new column, you'd either refer to the original df or use `.loc`, `.iloc`, or `.ix`, example:

```
In [29]:

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=list('abc'), data = np.random.randn(5,3))
df
Out[29]:
          a         b         c
0 -1.525011  0.778190 -1.010391
1  0.619824  0.790439 -0.692568
2  1.272323  1.620728  0.192169
3  0.193523  0.070921  1.067544
4  0.057110 -1.007442  1.706704
In [30]:

for index,row in df.iterrows():
    df.loc[index,'d'] = np.random.randint(0, 10)
df
Out[30]:
          a         b         c  d
0 -1.525011  0.778190 -1.010391  9
1  0.619824  0.790439 -0.692568  9
2  1.272323  1.620728  0.192169  1
3  0.193523  0.070921  1.067544  0
4  0.057110 -1.007442  1.706704  9
```

You can modify existing rows:

```
In [31]:
# reset the df by slicing
df = df[list('abc')]
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    row['b'] = np.random.randint(0, 10)
df
Out[31]:
          a  b         c
0 -1.525011  8 -1.010391
1  0.619824  2 -0.692568
2  1.272323  8  0.192169
3  0.193523  2  1.067544
4  0.057110  3  1.706704
```

But adding a new column using row won't work:

```
In [35]:

df = df[list('abc')]
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    row['d'] = np.random.randint(0,10)
df
Out[35]:
          a  b         c
0 -1.525011  8 -1.010391
1  0.619824  2 -0.692568
2  1.272323  8  0.192169
3  0.193523  2  1.067544
4  0.057110  3  1.706704
```

Answer (score 4):

```
row[col_head] = 1 ..
```

Please try the below line:

```
df.at[index,col_head]=1
```