# How to calculate ratio from two different pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to calculate sales ratio of retailer-sku across a period of weeks and then calculate the mean of retailer-sku across those weeks.

So far I've been able to calculate the sum of sales across weeks for sku's and then I have grouped the sales of retailer-sku across weeks.

Now I'm unable to find the way to calculate the ratio of sales across 'N' number of weeks of retailer sku.

Here is my code

```
score_period = [
        [201636, 201643],
        [201640, 201647],
        [201645, 201652],
        [201649, 201704],
        [201701, 201708]
    ]


    sku_group = df.groupby('Sku', as_index=False)
    sku_list = sku_group.groups.keys()

    for sku in sku_list:

        df_sku = df[df['Sku'] == sku]
        for period in score_period:
            df_period = df_sku[(df_sku['Week'] >= period[0]) &
                               (df_sku['Week'] <= period[1])]

            # sales of each week in period
            df_sum = df_period.groupby(['Week'], as_index=False)['WeekSales'].sum()
            # retailer sales sum per week
            sums = df_period.groupby(['Week', 'RetailerCode'], as_index=False)['WeekSales'].sum()

            for index, rows in sums.iterrows():
                sums['ratio'] = sums['WeekSales'] / df_sum[(df_sum['Week'])]['WeekSales']
```

Data

```
sales = [
    {'RetailerCode': 'RET001', 'Sku': 'SKU001', 'Week': 201636, 'WeekSales': 10},
    {'RetailerCode': 'RET002', 'Sku': 'SKU002', 'Week': 201636, 'WeekSales': 20},
    {'RetailerCode': 'RET003', 'Sku': 'SKU003', 'Week': 201636, 'WeekSales': 0},
    {'RetailerCode': 'RET004', 'Sku': 'SKU004', 'Week': 201636, 'WeekSales': 10},
    {'RetailerCode': 'RET001', 'Sku': 'SKU001', 'Week': 201637, 'WeekSales': 5},
    {'RetailerCode': 'RET002', 'Sku': 'SKU002', 'Week': 201637, 'WeekSales': 10},
    {'RetailerCode': 'RET003', 'Sku': 'SKU003', 'Week': 201637, 'WeekSales': 20},
    {'RetailerCode': 'RET004', 'Sku': 'SKU004', 'Week': 201637, 'WeekSales': 3},
]

df = pd.DataFrame(sales)
```

Expected results:

```
RET001 avg ratio = (Ratio of first week + Ratio of second week) / 2
RET002 avg ratio = (Ratio of first week + Ratio of second week) / 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Explanation

- At the last for-loop, **you should access rows, not sums** (whole table).
- Because you are iterate through the tables, you can not add column simply by `sum['ratio']`. **You have to use `sums.loc[index, 'ratio']`** (Explanation of this can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31458794/python-using-iterrows-to-create-columns))
- To match the week in `df_sum` and `sums`, you need to do `df_sum[df_sum['Week'] == rows['Week']`. **This will return value of `WeekSales` in `df_sum` that matches `Week` in current row.**

**Please check if the below code is what you are looking for.**

```
score_period = [
    [201636, 201643],
    [201640, 201647],
    [201645, 201652],
    [201649, 201704],
    [201701, 201708]
]
sku_group = df.groupby('Sku', as_index=False)
sku_list = sku_group.groups.keys()


sku_group = df.groupby('Sku', as_index=False)
sku_list = sku_group.groups.keys()
#for sku in sku_list:
#  df_sku = df[df['Sku'] == sku]
for period in score_period:
    df_period = df[(df['Week'] >= period[0]) & (df['Week'] <= period[1])]

    # sales of each week in period
    df_sum = df_period.groupby(['Week'], as_index=False)['WeekSales'].sum()
    # retailer sales sum per week
    sums = df_period.groupby(['Week', 'RetailerCode'], as_index=False)['WeekSales'].sum()
    for index, rows in sums.iterrows():
        sums.loc[index,'ratio'] = (rows['WeekSales']/df_sum[df_sum['Week']==rows['Week']]['WeekSales']).values
```

Result:

```
     Week RetailerCode  WeekSales     ratio
0  201636       RET001         10  0.250000
1  201636       RET002         20  0.500000
2  201636       RET003          0  0.000000
3  201636       RET004         10  0.250000
4  201637       RET001          5  0.131579
5  201637       RET002         10  0.263158
6  201637       RET003         20  0.526316
7  201637       RET004          3  0.078947
```

Comment: yes, i'm looking for it but also how to get to average of all ratio sales per period where a period can be N number of weeks.

Comment: Can you give more infomation on the formula of all ratio sales?

Comment: eg. for 4 weeks in a period a retailer ratio is sum of all weeks divide by 4 similarly its divide by 5 if the period is of 5 weeks.  so in our case RET001 avg ratio and say a period is 2 weeks, it is ratio of 201636 + 201637 divide by 2

Comment: I am a bit confused here.  For RET001, ratio is 0.25 for week 201636 and 0.131579 for week 201637. So we do (0.25+0.131579)/2 ? Because you have "SKU001  0.315789474" and I am not sure how this is calculated.

Comment: That is correct, I think I've made a mistake in pasting the result. Let me rectify

Comment: The approch is do sums.groupby('RetailerCode').count() to calculate total weeks, then sums.groupby('RetailerCode').sum() to calculate total  ratio. Then you divide total ratio by total weeks.